# Run VB.net program minimized

Tags: vb.net, minimized

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jq0F.png]

As shown in the picture, I want my vb.net application to run minimized like that a show a pop-up when the minimize button is hit. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: search for notification icon and context menu.there are plenty of examples

Comment: Google is your friend as @qwr mentioned there are plenty of examples on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

You can use the notifyicon control...Hide the form when it's minimized and show the notifyicon, otherwise, show the form and hide the notifyicon control...

Add notifyicon control

Add this code under the form resize event

```
 If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
     Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
     NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
     NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5, "System", "DoubleClick on the Icon to restore the application.", ToolTipIcon.Info)
     Me.Hide()
 End If
```

Under the doubleclick event of notifyicon control, add this code...

```
 Me.Show()
 Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
 NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
```

Comment: @user3292210 No problem. If it answered your question, please do mark my post as answered :) Thank you.